# Codenameone App on iPad uses wrong aspect ratio on every other start out of sleep

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

First, I am new to codenameone, so I'm sorry if the solution is obvious.
I have a problem where my codenameone app does resize the current form after a start from background, but just on the iPad. It does that only every other resume, so one time normal, background, resized format, background, normal.

In the simulator and on the iPhone the behavior is normal, just the iPad is messed up.

Can anybody point me in a direction? I think something gets perhaps called twice, but I don't know what... The code example for onstart() and onStop() and photos are attached..

Thank you!

rgds Vinc

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Controller.showSplash(); // go to splash screen. Splash screen forwards to mainMenu();
}

public void stop() {
    current = getCurrentForm();
    if (current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog) current).dispose();
        current = getCurrentForm();
    }
}
```

//Gui Builder code

```
public MainMenu(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
    initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
}

protected com.codename1.ui.Label gui_Label = new com.codename1.ui.Label();
protected com.codename1.ui.Container gui_Box_Layout_Y = new com.codename1.ui.Container(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout(1, 1));
protected com.codename1.components.ScaleImageButton gui_Scaled_Button = new com.codename1.components.ScaleImageButton();
protected com.codename1.components.ScaleImageButton gui_Scaled_Button_1 = new com.codename1.components.ScaleImageButton();
protected com.codename1.components.ScaleImageButton gui_Scaled_Button_2 = new com.codename1.components.ScaleImageButton();
protected com.codename1.ui.Label gui_Label_1 = new com.codename1.ui.Label();
protected com.codename1.ui.Button gui_Button = new com.codename1.ui.Button();

private void guiBuilderBindComponentListeners() {
    EventCallbackClass callback = new EventCallbackClass();
    gui_Scaled_Button.addActionListener(callback);
    gui_Scaled_Button_1.addActionListener(callback);
    gui_Scaled_Button_2.addActionListener(callback);
    gui_Button.addActionListener(callback);
}

class EventCallbackClass implements com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener, com.codename1.ui.events.DataChangedListener {
    private com.codename1.ui.Component cmp;
    public EventCallbackClass(com.codename1.ui.Component cmp) {
        this.cmp = cmp;
    }

    public EventCallbackClass() {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
        com.codename1.ui.Component sourceComponent = ev.getComponent();

        if(sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() != null && (sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() instanceof com.codename1.components.MultiButton || sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() instanceof com.codename1.components.SpanButton)) {
            sourceComponent = sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent();
        }

        if(sourceComponent == gui_Scaled_Button) {
            onScaled_ButtonActionEvent(ev);
        }
        if(sourceComponent == gui_Scaled_Button_1) {
            onScaled_Button_1ActionEvent(ev);
        }
        if(sourceComponent == gui_Scaled_Button_2) {
            onScaled_Button_2ActionEvent(ev);
        }
        if(sourceComponent == gui_Button) {
            onButtonActionEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
    }
}
private void initGuiBuilderComponents(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
    guiBuilderBindComponentListeners();
    setLayout(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout());
    setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    setScrollableX(false);
    setScrollableY(false);
            setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    setInlineAllStyles("fgColor:ffffff; opacity:220;");
    setTitle("");
    setName("ToolBox");
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)getLayout()).setPreferredWidthMM((float)156.8586);
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)getLayout()).setPreferredHeightMM((float)171.04149);
    addComponent(gui_Label);
    addComponent(gui_Box_Layout_Y);
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.setPreferredSizeStr("64.9873mm 52.921253mm");
            gui_Box_Layout_Y.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.setName("Box_Layout_Y");
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Box_Layout_Y.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "24.82299% auto 28.533901% auto").setReferenceComponents(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "-1 -1 0 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0");
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.addComponent(gui_Scaled_Button);
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.addComponent(gui_Scaled_Button_1);
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.addComponent(gui_Scaled_Button_2);
            gui_Scaled_Button.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Scaled_Button.setName("Scaled_Button");
    gui_Scaled_Button.setIcon(resourceObjectInstance.getImage("CrewRest_V02.jpg"));
            gui_Scaled_Button_1.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Scaled_Button_1.setName("Scaled_Button_1");
    gui_Scaled_Button_1.setIcon(resourceObjectInstance.getImage("Fuel_V02.jpg"));
            gui_Scaled_Button_2.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Scaled_Button_2.setName("Scaled_Button_2");
    gui_Scaled_Button_2.setIcon(resourceObjectInstance.getImage("Snowtam_V02.jpg"));
    addComponent(gui_Label_1);
    addComponent(gui_Button);
    gui_Label.setPreferredSizeStr("182.2608mm 10.0mm");
    gui_Label.setUIID("LabelGrey");
            gui_Label.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Label.setInlineAllStyles("bgColor:5f6a6d; transparency:255; opacity:255; margin:0.0mm 0.0mm 0.0mm 0.0mm;");
    gui_Label.setName("Label");
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Label.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Label, "92.31431% 0.0mm 0.0mm 0.0mm").setReferenceComponents(gui_Label, "-1 -1 -1 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Label, "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0");
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.setPreferredSizeStr("64.9873mm 52.921253mm");
            gui_Box_Layout_Y.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.setName("Box_Layout_Y");
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Box_Layout_Y.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "24.82299% auto 28.533901% auto").setReferenceComponents(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "-1 -1 0 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0");
            gui_Label_1.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Label_1.setInlineAllStyles("bgColor:ffffff; transparency:255;");
    gui_Label_1.setName("Label_1");
    gui_Label_1.setIcon(resourceObjectInstance.getImage("AeroLogic_Logo.jpg"));
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Label_1.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Label_1, "0.0mm auto auto auto").setReferenceComponents(gui_Label_1, "-1 -1 -1 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Label_1, "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0");
    gui_Button.setPreferredSizeStr("7.1972904mm 4.022015mm");
    gui_Button.setUIID("ButtonInfo");
            gui_Button.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
    gui_Button.setInlineAllStyles("fgColor:ffffff;");
    gui_Button.setName("Button");
    com.codename1.ui.FontImage.setMaterialIcon(gui_Button,"\ue88e".charAt(0));
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Button.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Button, "auto 2.3285353mm auto auto").setReferenceComponents(gui_Button, "0 0 0 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Button, "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0");
}// </editor-fold>
```

[After resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwXsV.png)

[Normal after every second resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1maR.png)

Comment: If it works correctly on iPhone it should work on iPad too. Can you explain the scenario in more detail e.g. you launch app in portrait. Exit it. Rotate the device then launch it again or go to it through the task manager? Does it refresh after a second or after touch? Is the app locked in portrait mode or has any settings defined? What'a the OS version/device version for the iPad?

Comment: What version of iOS is the iPad running?  And which iPad.

Comment: ipad 2 Air, iOS 12.1.4;

Comment: @ajeferson: I launch the app in any direction, splashscreen, homescreen--> all normal. I send to sleep with home button, select the app icon again, it comes out of sleep, aspect ratio is changed (see pictures). I send to sleep and restore again-->all normal. When the aspect ratio is wrong i navigate to other form or rotate screen from portrait to landscape or vice versa-->all normal.

Comment: We're looking into it, this could be a regression

Comment: So far I can't replicate this.  Can you post an issue in the CN1 issue tracker and include a self-contained test case that I can build and test.  And provide steps to reproduce there.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new

Comment: i entered an excerpt of the code for the main page.

Comment: i also tried to build a version only for the iPad, but no change in behaviour.